# Which File Has A Display Subtotal,Shipping and Handling, Grandtotal?

Tags: pdf, magento-1.9, invoice

Which File Has A Display Subtotal,Shipping and Handling, Grandtotal Lbael or It's Value? in Magento?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure about this Refer Below file path is to change the invoice pdf.
`

> /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php

copy the above file path to

> /app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Items/Invoice/Default.php

see below code to edit the label

```
 $lines[$i][] = array(
                'text'  => $priceData['subtotal'],
                'feed'  => $feedSubtotal,
                'font'  => 'bold',
                'align' => 'right'
            );
            $i++;
```

And i'm not sure about the value. Please check below file path

> /app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order/Pdf/Total/Default.php